# Unable to remove master -> child subform links in microsoft access 2003

Tags: winforms, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am having an issue removing the master -> child link fields in an access subreport data form.  I have tried every avenue to remove them, using the properties window of the subreport as well as the link wizard.  I have also deleted the subreport from the database and then gone as far as re-importing the existing objects into a new access instance.  As soon as I re-added the subform back in and name it the same name the link fields show back up.  Something is apparently corrupt, but I have run out of ideas at this point on how to clear them.

Any Ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks
Doug

Comment: Have you turned off Name AutoCorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Thanks Raj - Yes the issue is due to the fact that the sub-report was bound to a table and was in fact "magically" inferring the link fields.  In order to remove the links permanently you have to remove any reference to a data-source...table, query, sql etc.

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: I don't really understand the issue. Sure, Access automatically infers the links, but if they aren't what you want, you can easily edit the Link Child and Link Master properties of the subform/subreport control. You don't have to remove the data source at all, just edit the properties directly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove them from the SubReport / SubForm object on the Master page / Master form. If you drop and recreate the child form the linkage is still not broken.

If not, VBA code could actually be setting these properties. You should open up a module and search globally for the value (the one that is set in the link fields property).

Also, if the linkages are set in the table as relationships, every time you add the child form object, access with auto-magically fill up the relationships for you. If you want to remove them, you may have to do that manually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Raj -  Yes I have removed them from the subform object but this does not remove the linkage although the properties box seems to allude that they are gone.  Also I am not setting any links in vba.  Thanks for the good ideas though.